# How to count each users records in database table and display count in view file

Tags: php, laravel, database, relationship

I want to get job count for each user but i am getting the error Using $this when not in object context (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\project104\resources\views\users\show.blade.php). I will appreciate any help, Thanks in advance.

User model function

```
 public function jobs()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(App\Job::class);
        }

        public static function getJobsCountAttribute(){
            return $this->jobs()->count();
        }
```

Job model

```
  public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\User::class);
    }
```

In view file

```
   @php
    $getJobsCountAttribute = \App\User::getJobsCountAttribute();
    @endphp
    {{ $getJobsCountAttribute }}
```

Comment: it is php issue you are using static in one function and other is not static

Comment: I guess it`s not @Puneet Sharma i tried makeng all methods static but got the same error

Comment: please don't use static. Static is for where you like to call a method directly laravel do direct injection static. expect some places like controller

Comment: Okey thank you very much @Puneet Sharma